# Having issues with python nested dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7

I am having a few newbie issues with python where, despite all the suggestions I've seen online, I can't access the value in a listed dictionary I'm trying to access.

This is the data the API returns:

```
OrderedDict([(u'totalSize', 1), (u'done', True), (u'records', [OrderedDict([(u'attributes', OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Contact'), (u'url', u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Contact/00346000004eV89AAE')])), (u'Name', u'This is my name')])])])
```

This is my most recent attempt:

```
dict['records']['Name']

    print(dict['records']['Name'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `dict['records']` is a *list* of ordered dictionaries, as the error message tells you. Also `dict` is a bad name for a dictionary as it shadows the built-in.

Comment: I think you are expecting the dicts to be nested, but as you can see from running `type(dict['records'])` you have actually created a sub-list, not a dict. Also, its best not to use dict as the name of your dictionary as this is also a python class. It can get confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the brackets around the nested `OrderedDict`, so

```
OrderedDict([..., (u'records', OrderedDict([...]))])
```

instead of

```
OrderedDict([..., (u'records', [OrderedDict([...])])])
```

This is because `OrderedDict` expects its argument to be a list of key-value pairs. In your code, the value for the key `'records'` is a list containing a single dictionary. You want it to just be a dictionary.

EDIT: Since you can't change the data that's being used to construct the dictionary there are a couple of workarounds.

#### Workaround #1

Put up with a more annoying calling scheme:

```
d['records'][0]['Name']
```

This is the simpler workaround but of course it is ugly and harder to understand.

#### Workaround #2

Wrap the `OrderedDict` in a new class that customizes the item access syntax.

```
class MyOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        ret = super().__getitem__(key)
        if isinstance(ret, list):
            if ret and isinstance(ret[0], OrderedDict):
                return ret[0]
        return ret
```

This makes it so that if the return value of call like `d['records']` is a list whose first element is an `OrderedDict`, then the `OrderedDict` will be returned instead of the list, so that you can just chain the item accesses. You would write it like this:

```
d = MyOrderedDict(api_data)
d['records']['Name'] # 'This is my name'
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that the nested dictionaries is the output an API returns so I can't really modify how the API sends the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). That works perfectly. I'll use #1 as a short term solution but I'll definintley make sure that I implement #2 after I sit down and figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The data structure you get from your API has a list of dictionaries as `dict['records']`. You seem to be expecting a dictionary there instead.

Since the list has only a single element, you may just need to index the list to get the value you want: `dict['records'][0]['name']`.

However, if there might be a different number of inner dictionaries in the list, you may want to write list comprehension (or explicit loop) instead. Try something like `[inner['name'] for inner in dict['records']]`. This will give you a list of names, with the same number of items as the `dict['records']` list.

Note that it's probably a bad idea to use `dict` as a variable name in your code, since that's the name of the builtin dictionary type. Using it for something else can lead to unexpected errors in later code (when you want to create a dictionary but end up calling something else). This isn't the cause of your issue indexing your data structure, just a way to improve your code a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate the explination and it worked perfectly. I don't normally name dictionaries "dict" but I just did it when showing an example of my problem. I didn't realize it could create issues though, thanks. I'll definitely make sure I don't do it in the future.